# Case using at Join

Tags: sql, mysqli, left-join

I'm trying to use case function at Join and I failed to execute the Query.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
left join vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_history on 
CASE
WHEN vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id = (substring(vw_public_material_history.comments,12,6))

then vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id
else null
end
```

What I wish to get is join rows only if I have "true" from the "When"

I feel I miss something here.

Comment: Skip the `case` expression, use `AND`/`OR` instead!

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` expression makes no sense. A `CASE` expression results in a value, in your case for example in `material_request_id`. So you'd get

```
left join vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_history on material_request_id
```

in case of a string match. You do notice that this `ON` clause is incomplete?

You are probably looking for

```
left join vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_history on 
  vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id = 
  (substring(vw_public_material_history.comments,12,6))
```

That would read better with table aliases:

```
from vw_public_request_material_location_mir mir
left join vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_history hist on 
  mir.material_request_id = (substring(hist.comments,12,6))
```

As to your data model: It seems strange that you have an ID hidden in a string. You may want to re-consider your table design.

Comment: Thanks, for your help, I tried to execute the left join as you suggest but I got the next error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'tem' to data type int." the data at "comments" contain characters & numbers and I extracting only the numbers.

Comment: Obviously not. It seems you are extracting the string 'term' which is not a number.

Comment: I think I have here another issue, most of the data I have at comments looks like this "yg per MIR#332166|;Yaniv" but I also have rows that contains only characters. any idea how to over come this?

Comment: Well the best idea would be another data model. A column `comment` should contain some comment, not structured data in which you expect to find an ID in a certain place.

Comment: You tagged your request with mysqli. The error message, however, doesn't sound at all like MySQL. AFAIK when MySQL converts a string that starts with a non-digit character to number the result is zero (which I've always considered dirty), which would avoid a conversion problem. The error essage you got sounds like SQL Server. Please check this.